# Spring scheduled tasks

Tags: spring, task, spring-scheduled

I'm trying to use spring scheduled tasks for my scheduled jobs, I have one scheduler configured for multiple tasks executors as below

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="ABCTaskScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="ABCTaskExecutor" method="execute"
            cron="some_expression_1" />     
    <task:scheduled ref="DEFTaskExecutor" method="execute"
            cron="some_expression_1" /> 
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

My question in how can I make the task executor list dynamic, so that I do not have to change my spring config each time I have to add a new task executor.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a `TaskScheduler` such as the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` as a simple bean and then schedule you executors in code like this:

```
scheduler.schedule(myTask, new CronTrigger("* 15 9-17 * * MON-FRI"));
```

See the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) for the full rundown on this.

Comment: Thanks for reply .. due to few limitations we do not want to move to annotations based TaskScheduler?